# How to insert image to database using phpmyadmin 'insert' tab

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database I created through phpmyadmin. 
Basically, I would like to know how to insert an image (or to be specific, insert an image relative path) to my database through the phpmyadmin 'insert' tab.
Any suggestions on fields and data types would be great!

Comment: basically i would like to insert images through the phpmyadmin interface, through the 'insert' tab. sorry if I worded my question really badly, ignore everything! @Dagon

Comment: type in the file name and perhaps the path of the image location that the browser would use. not sure what else to say

Comment: @mar insert just the path of the file or insert the image as BLOB?

Answer (score 2):

I always save the path where the file is being uploaded, Take a look at the following example to see if it fit your needs:

Page 1 : Here your are going to have your form to upload the images files

```
´

<html>
<head>
<title>Pagina 1 form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>This is our upload control</div>

<form name="form" action="page2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="foto">
    <p>
    <button>Subir archivo</button>
 </form>

 </body>
```

´

Page 2: This is the one which is going to receive the file and save it to the table you want

```
´
<?php 
$file_get = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];

$file_to_saved = "dcuments/".$file_get; //Documents folder, should exist in       your host in there you're going to save the file just uploaded
move_uploaded_file($temp, $file_to_saved);

echo $file_to_saved;

$insert_img = mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table (field_image) values  ('".$file_to_saved."')");
if ($insert_img) {
# code...
echo "Img inserted successfully";
}
else{
 echo "There is something wrong with this code. Eff!";
}

 ?>
```

´

Hope this helps! XD

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` return `true` or `false` depending on success, but you never know if it returns `true` in your case. I don't like quality of your code, but your approach is quite right, so +1

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on fields and data types would be great!

If you **have** to store the images into the database (no recommended), the column type depends on the image size that you are going to insert.

**TINYBLOB** A binary large object column with a maximum length of 255 (2^8 - 1) characters.

**BLOB**A binary large object column with a maximum length of 65535 (2^16 - 1) characters.

**MEDIUMBLOB** A binary large object column with a maximum length of 16777215 (2^24 - 1) characters.

**TINYBLOB** A binary large object column with a maximum length of 255 (2^8 - 1) characters.

**BLOB** A binary large object column with a maximum length of 65535 (2^16 - 1) characters.

**MEDIUMBLOB** A binary large object column with a maximum length of 16777215 (2^24 - 1) characters.

**LONGBLOB** A binary large object column with a maximum length of 4294967295 (2^32 - 1) characters.

**Create DDL Statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
 Image LONGBLOB, 
);
```

If you **don't have** to store the image into the database, [alejo-blue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895264/alejo-blue) answer will work for you